# Getting typeof error undefined and 0 value google spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I am having a hard time trying to catch or prevent an undefined error when trying to get data. This error prevents the script from running. The script is meant to grab all the AppIDs from A2:A from the spreadsheet. From there, it fills in some basic info about the game; Name, Free or not and has cards.

One of the errors: `TypeError: Cannot read property "0" from undefined. (line 40, file "Code")`

Line 40: `var gameId = values[i][0];`

[Spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ukMpY4bXwl4BLJJwsrU9mlSPvc68GWs_Hs2dSpBBiqo/edit?usp=sharing)

Here is the code I was able to put together and working to an extent

```
function onOpen() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  options = [
    {name:"Update Headers", functionName:"createHeaders"},
    {name:"Update Games", functionName:"steamData"}
    ];
  ss.addMenu("Steam Info", options);
}


function createHeaders() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];

  // Freezes the first row
  sheet.setFrozenRows(1);

  //Set header values
  var headerNames = [
    ["APPID","GAME NAME","HAS CARDS","IS FREE?","KEY","DLC KEYS","SG LINK","WINNER","SG STATUS"]
   ];

  //Set range
  var range = sheet.getRange("A1:I1");

  //Set range with values
  range.setValues(headerNames);
}

function steamData() 
{
  var values = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getDataRange().getValues();
  //values[i][y] y is index of the column starting from 0
  //values[y][i] y is index of the row starting from 0
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
  for( var i = 0; sheet.getLastRow() > 0; i--) 
  {
    if ( i === 0 ){ continue; }
    var gameId = values[i][0];
    var url = 'http://store.steampowered.com/api/appdetails?appids='+gameId;
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {'muteHttpExceptions': true});
    var json = response.getContentText();
    var data = JSON.parse(json);
    var gameData = data[gameId].data;
    var hasCards = "No";
    for(var j = 0; j < gameData.categories.length; j++) {
      if(gameData.categories[j].id === 29) {
        hasCards = "Yes";
       }
     }
    var cellData = [
      [gameId.toString(),gameData.name,hasCards,gameData.is_free]
    ];
    if ( i === 1 ){ continue; }
    Logger.log("A"+i);
    var selection = sheet.getRange("A"+ i +":D"+ i);
    selection.setValues(cellData);
  }
}
```

**Updated code that works now**

```
function onOpen() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  options = [
    {name:"Update Headers", functionName:"createHeaders"},
    {name:"Update Games", functionName:"steamData"}
    ];
  ss.addMenu("Steam Info", options);

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];

  // Freezes the first row
  sheet.setFrozenRows(1);

  //Set header values
  var headerNames = [
    ["APPID","GAME NAME","HAS CARDS","IS FREE?","KEY","DLC KEYS","SG LINK","WINNER","SG STATUS"]
   ];

  //Set range
  var range = sheet.getRange("A1:I1");

  //Set range with values
  range.setValues(headerNames);
}

function steamData() 
{
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
  var range = sheet.getRange("A2:A");
  var cells = range.getValues();
  var last = sheet.getLastRow().toString();
  for(var i = 0; i < last-1; i++) 
  {
    if(cells[i] == 'APPID') {
      continue;
    }
//    Logger.log("B"+(i+2)+":D"+(i+2));
    var gameId = cells[i].toString();
    var url = 'http://store.steampowered.com/api/appdetails?appids='+gameId;
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {'muteHttpExceptions': true});
    var json = response.getContentText();
    var data = JSON.parse(json);
    var gameData = data[gameId].data;
    var hasCards = "No";
    for(var j = 0; j < gameData.categories.length; j++) {
      if(gameData.categories[j].id == 29) {
        hasCards = "Yes";
      }
    }
    var cellData = [
      [gameData.name,hasCards,gameData.is_free]
    ];
    var selection = sheet.getRange("B"+(i+2)+":D"+(i+2));
    selection.setValues(cellData);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For whatever reason, the value[i] is undefined.  Try printing i. Is it negative? Should this `for( var i = 0; sheet.getLastRow() > 0; i--)` instead be i++? Also, the second expression in the for loop should be defined in terms of i.  If sheet.getLastRow() returns any positive integer, the loop will run forever.

Comment: I updated the for statement to `for( var i = 0; sheet.getLastRow() >= i; i++)`. Also added `i = i.toString();` due to it adding a decimal .0 to every number. Now the issue I am running into now, is that since it counts from 0-10 (11 numbers). I am not able to get row A11 since i only goes to 10.

Comment: Can you print sheet.getLastRow() and paste it here? It looks like rows start at 1 so you could do `for(var i = 1; i <= sheet.getLastRow() + 1; i++)`

Comment: sheet.getLastRow() outputs 6 or if the more data is added, that number goes up and vice versa.

Comment: `i = 2; i <= sheet.getLastRow() ; i++)` should do what you want.  Looks like row 1 is your column names, so the data starts at row 2 and goes up to and includes 6.

Comment: That does the trick for getting the rows to be A2 - A7 but I am getting `TypeError: Cannot read property "0" from undefined. (line 40, file "Code")`. I am thinking that its trying to get an array value of 7 or outside of the array.

Comment: Thats probably the issue.  Try `i = 2; i < sheet.getLastRow(); i++`. You should print your gameIds out to make sure youre getting all of them.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144987/discussion-between-ryahn-and-stephen-l).

Answer (score 0):

After messing around with more of the code and looking at some more documentation. Was able to get it working. Also thank you @Stephen L

```
function onOpen() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  options = [
    {name:"Update Headers", functionName:"createHeaders"},
    {name:"Update Games", functionName:"steamData"}
    ];
  ss.addMenu("Steam Info", options);

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];

  // Freezes the first row
  sheet.setFrozenRows(1);

  //Set header values
  var headerNames = [
    ["APPID","GAME NAME","HAS CARDS","IS FREE?","KEY","DLC KEYS","SG LINK","WINNER","SG STATUS"]
   ];

  //Set range
  var range = sheet.getRange("A1:I1");

  //Set range with values
  range.setValues(headerNames);
}

function steamData() 
{
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
  var range = sheet.getRange("A2:A");
  var cells = range.getValues();
  var last = sheet.getLastRow().toString();
  for(var i = 0; i < last-1; i++) 
  {
    if(cells[i] == 'APPID') {
      continue;
    }
//    Logger.log("B"+(i+2)+":D"+(i+2));
    var gameId = cells[i].toString();
    var url = 'http://store.steampowered.com/api/appdetails?appids='+gameId;
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {'muteHttpExceptions': true});
    var json = response.getContentText();
    var data = JSON.parse(json);
    var gameData = data[gameId].data;
    var hasCards = "No";
    for(var j = 0; j < gameData.categories.length; j++) {
      if(gameData.categories[j].id == 29) {
        hasCards = "Yes";
      }
    }
    var cellData = [
      [gameData.name,hasCards,gameData.is_free]
    ];
    var selection = sheet.getRange("B"+(i+2)+":D"+(i+2));
    selection.setValues(cellData);
  }
}
```